# Text positioning in tikz arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to place correctly some kind of legend below or above an arrow in a circuit. My intention is representing an external stimulus with an arrow and that text. However the only way I've found is using a *short* with a current arrow instead of a line with an ending arrow. Here is my MWE. Attach the result too.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages, american currents, european resistors] 
\draw 
        (-2.5,2) to [short,i=Solar Flux] (-0.5,1.3)
        (0,0) to[I, i_>=$I_{Light}$] (0,2)   %% Note _>= instead of >=
        to[short, -*] (1.5,2)
        (1.5,2) to[diode, i=$I_{Diode}$, -*] (1.5,0)
        to[short, -*] (0,0)


        (1.5,2) to[short, i_>=$I_{out}$] (3,2)
        (1.5,0) to[short] (3,0)
        (3,2) to [open,v^>=$V_{out}$] (3,0)


\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you may do like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

        \begin{circuitikz}[american voltages, american currents, european resistors] 
        \draw 
        (-2.5,2) to [short,i=\ ] (-0.5,1.3)
        (-2.5,1.75) to [short,i=\ ] (-0.5,1.05)
        (-2.5,1.5) to [short,i=\ ] (-0.5,0.8)
        (0,0) to[I, i_>=$I_{Light}$] (0,2)   %% Note _>= instead of >=
        to[short, -*] (1.5,2)
        (1.5,2) to[diode, i=$I_{Diode}$, -*] (1.5,0)
        to[short, -*] (0,0)


        (1.5,2) to[short, i_>=$I_{out}$] (3,2)
        (1.5,0) to[short] (3,0)
        (3,2) to [open,v^>=$V_{out}$] (3,0);
\node at (-1.5,0.75){$Solar Flux$};

        \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So nice, that's it. Thanks